# Is it bad practice to have a requirejs package with no main script?

Tags: requirejs, amd

Lets say i have a bunch of js view scripts defined as AMD modules in directory 'views'.

Rather than listing them all out in the requirejs config, i could just do this:

```
require = {
  baseUrl: 'js',
  packages: [
    { name:'views',location:'app/views' }
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

I then require them as `['views/sunset', 'views/ocean']` (or `'./ocean'` if from another view) etc.

This saves me a whopping 20 seconds or so versus listing them all out individually in the require config, and arguably makes my define() calls more expressive (i.e it's clear which scripts are components, which are utilities etc)

Essentially i'm treating the directory as a package, but there is no main script, so `require(['views'])` would return a 404. Is there any reason why this approach might be considered bad practice? Are there issues with this that i'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

In my previous job we did not have `main.js` file because each page had different modules so they were loaded dynamically based on the content of the page. I didn't notice any issues with that.

Your solution seems to be similar. If you do not have any errors, it's fine :)

`main.js` is not required but it is recommended by RequireJS from what I remember